# How to prevent Babel from formatting the generated code?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

When using Babel to modify the AST of a JavaScript code and writing the generated code back to the original file, I observed that the original file gets reformatted. However, I do not want the code to be formatted. How can I resolve this issue?

I hope the output file maintains the same format as the parsed file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[`@babel/generator`](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-generator) uses one predefined way to generate code, since it is used (mostly) to generate code that will be minified anyways.

Avoid any kind of formatting is impossible since [`@babel/parser`](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-parser) produce **AST**(Abstract Syntax Tree), data structure that has no information about formatting.

To format code in a way you like you have a couple options:

- use [recast](https://github.com/benjamn/recast), it works good for most cases and changes least possible amount of code with a some kind of magic , sounds good, but is not maintained;
- use [ESLint](https://eslint.org/), but you should configure it before, or use preset, I wrote this one, for example: [`@putout/eslint-config`](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/eslint-config#readme);
- Use [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) - standard formatter with small amount of options;
- Use [`@putout/printer`](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/eslint-config#readme) - formatter for Babel AST with lots of options developed by me;

No matter what option you choose, you must choose one of formatters to have your codebase consistent before and after applying changes to AST.